# Iterating through LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

Let me first apologize if this is ridiculously elementary.  This is my first time programming.

The issue here is that I need to print out a LinkedList.  Could someone guide me as to what I'm doing wrong?  Here's what I have:

```
public class Queue {

private LinkedList list;

public Queue() { 
    list = new LinkedList(); 
}
}

public class BankQueue {

static Queue q = new Queue();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Insert a menu with a list of possible choices

public static void printQueue(Queue q) {
    for (String s : q) {
        System.out.println(q);
    }
}
```

I keep getting errors saying that say that I can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable.  Thanks for the help.  It's sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over a *list*, not over *your class instance* that in fact doesn't implement `Iterable`, like

```
public void printQueue(Queue q) {
     for(String s : q.getList()) {
         //do anything with your string
    }
}
```

Of course, it implies that your `LinkedList` is in fact `LinkedList<String>` and that you have a getter for `list` field declared in your class like `public List<String> getList() { return list; }`.

Comment: I had to add the getter, but that fixed my issue.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your class `Queue` is not iterable.

Incidentally, its name collides with `java.util.Queue`, which *is* iterable.

If you're actually trying to iterate over the `list` member of `Queue`, you'll need to provide a getter for that (it's private), or write yourself a Visitor.

Comment: I actually did not realize that there was already a use for "Queue".  Perhaps I'll change the name of this thing...

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be iterating over the `list` member of `q`.  You would need to implement the `Iterable` interface, or iterate over `q.list` directly.

The really proper way to do it would be to implement `Iterable`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use iterator to loop through the LinkedList like below:

```
iterator = q.iterator(); 
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  System.out.print(iterator.next()+" ");  
}
```

Comment: The OP has defined his own `Queue` class, which doesn't implement `Iterable`, and therefore does not have an `iterator()` method.

Comment: Ah. That explains why I couldn't get that to work.  Sorry for the confusion with the class name.  I didn't realize that there was already a use for "Queue".  Thanks anyway.